# format date to 'hh.mm.yyyy' in query

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

How to format date in 'hh.mm.yyyy', in select query (oracle), if you don't know which format has date in DB (actually i'll know, but it will be changed in time)

Comment: I think the best for you would be to treat the date as a date when in the db and worry about presentation of dates in some client instead.

Comment: Look like i'll find the way: using sql func to_char(), but one trouble - thats char, not date. P.S. Thats clients db, cannot modify that.

Comment: so the date is stored as a string...and the format might change in the future? will the already existing dates be updated to the new format?

Comment: You've mixed a time format with the date format elements: `hh` is the hour of the day (12-hour clock), `mm` is the month number, `yyyy` is the year.

Answer (score 3):

You can use TO_CHAR(column,'dd.mm.yyyy')

```
select TO_CHAR(OrderDate,'dd.mm.yyyy')
  from MyTable;
```

or you can alter session format

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='dd.mm.yyyy';
```

by default format is "DD-MON-YY"

Comment: +1, unless the underlying column is not a date (not sure, but the question seems to suggest the underlying column is stored as a string)